# How to deploy my wildfly 21 Rest API to heroku with .war file

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, heroku

I have created a Dynamic Web Project on eclipse building a Rest API with wildfly on eclipse using Maven  that perfectly runs locally, but I am experiencing some issues while trying to deploy my project on Heroku.

I have checked the heroku deploy:war and it works when deploying but gives a strange error message saying that heroku finds a problem trying to delete a temporary file because it is being used by another process.

Error:

```
heroku war:deploy  C:/Users/jorge/Desktop/RestApi/RestApi/target/RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --app abyss-layers
Uploading RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: abyss-layers
       - including: webapp-runner.jar
       - including: target/RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-----> Creating build...
       - file: slug.tgz
       - size: 22MB
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote:
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 73.8M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v3
remote:        https://abyss-layers.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote:
-----> Done
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to delete C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy2618339899556532853
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:46)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\Users\jorge\AppData\Local\Temp\heroku-deploy2618339899556532853\heroku\app\.heroku-deploy: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:92)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:274)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.delete(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:105)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.delete(Files.java:1145)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:21)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable$1.visitFile(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:16)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2803)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2875)
        at com.heroku.sdk.deploy.DeleteDirectoryRunnable.run(DeleteDirectoryRunnable.java:44)
        ... 1 more
```

This is what my pom.xml file looks like:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>API</groupId>
  <artifactId>API</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <finalName>helloworld</finalName>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>javax</groupId> 
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId> 
        <version>7.0</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
        <type>jar</type> 
    </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.wildfly.core</groupId> 
        <artifactId>wildfly-server</artifactId> 
        <version>2.2.0.Final</version> 
        <scope>provided</scope> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>API</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 
</web-app>
```

I also found some info to try to deploy using a webapp runner but it is based on tomcat, and also using a plugin that goes like this:

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
      </plugin>
```

and after setting the app name in the pom.xml, and executing mvn clean heroku:deploy-war -e -X as it is stated on https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin it gives this error:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.489 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-04T17:34:59+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project RestApi: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\RestApi\RestApi\target\RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\META-INF -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project RestApi: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\RestApi\RestApi\target\RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\META-INF
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\RestApi\RestApi\target\RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\META-INF
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete C:\Users\jorge\Desktop\RestApi\RestApi\target\RestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\META-INF
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:249)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:158)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete (Cleaner.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute (CleanMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

Thank you in advance to any of you who can give me any help!

Answer (score 0):

`heroku war:deploy` creates a temporary file that contains your project in a package that is understood by Heroku. This happens on your local machine. It tries to clean up those temporary files by deleting them.

I don't know which process might use this file causing the error, but as you noticed, this will not influence the deployment to Heroku itself.

The output of your `heroku-maven-plugin` is interesting. It's not the Heroku plugin that fails, but Maven's own `clean` plugin. Can you try running `mvn heroku:deploy-war` and see if that works?

In any case, I logged a bug for this and will make it a warning instead of a crash when the temporary files cannot be deleted.